# Права доступа в MODX

Tags: modx

Создал пользователя контент-менеджер, но в migx не могу загрузить картинку.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Слишком размытый вопрос. Куча подводных камней начиная от прав доступа к источнику файлов.

Answer (score 1):

Первое чтобы я проверил это источник файлов для картинки скорей всего стоит Filesystem а для менеджера создан другой